# jenkins doesn't find path **/* when Archiving artifacts

Tags: jenkins, archive, artifacts

i want to archive the artifacts in the path '**/*' but i'm getting the error:

```
 ‘**/*’ doesn’t match anything: ‘**’ exists but not ‘**/*’
```

under workspace i have a folder named 'build' and that folder contains the file that should be archived

from what i understand '**' should go to the build folder and the '*' should get the file
i tried use backslash('\') instead or **/*.* or **//* none of these worked, also when i try build/* it says build doesn't exist

console output:

```
Archiving artifacts  
‘**/*’ doesn’t match anything: ‘**’ exists but not ‘**/*’  
No artifacts found that match the file pattern "**/*". Configuration error?
```

update:

i found out that the workspace that it's trying to access isn't on the Jenkins server but on another server that the test is connecting using 'SSH site'.
how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you said the folder name under you project called build that you want all files under it to archive it use:

```
build/*.*
```